# SQLite: Create blobs table from SELECT WHERE query

Tags: sqlite, blob, converters

Is there a reasonably fast way to convert an sqlite database table into another table where all rows sharing the same value in one of the columns are appended into one string and stored as a blob?

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO new VALUES(<id>,blob) WHERE blob IN (SELECT blobber(*) FROM old WHERE id=<id>);
```

I'd have to add that `<id>` is not `UNIQUE`, as each identical entity can have multiple features. Therefore the serialization in `blobber()` would require two different separators.

Comment: What is `blobber` ?

Comment: "all rows sharing the same value in one of the columns are appended into one string and stored as a blob"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following may be along the lines of what you want :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable AS SELECT id,CAST(col1||col2||col3 AS BLOB) AS allcols FROM oldtable;
```

- assuming 3 columns in the original table, namely **col1**, **col2** and **col3**
- this is without the WHERE clause as *where all rows sharing the same value in one of the columns* is unclear/ambiguous.

Consider the following example :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oldtable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oldtable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT);
INSERT INTO oldtable (col1,col2,col3) VALUES 
    ('','',''),('A','B','C'),('123','123','123'),('C','D','E'),('456','456','456'),
    (x'00FF',x'01FE',x'02FD'),(x'00FF',x'00FF',x'00FF'),(x'00FF','ABC',x'FF00');
SELECT * FROM oldtable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable AS SELECT id,CAST(col1||col2||col3 AS BLOB) AS allcols FROM oldtable;
SELECT * FROM newtable;
```

The original table (the first SELECT query) :-

[image]

Whilst the new table (2nd SELECT query) :-

[image]

## Additional re comment

> So it is not possible to cast mutiple rows into one blob using a row
>   and a column separator? Or perhaps by building an intermediate table
>   as above and then casting all allcols for the same id into another
>   table's allrows?

Yes that is possible, as an example where the **id** column is the multiple rows column. The Aggregate function **group_concat**, in conjunction with the GROUP BY clause can be used as follows. :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oldtable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oldtable (id INTEGER, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT);
INSERT INTO oldtable (id,col1,col2,col3) VALUES 
    (1,'','',''),(2,'A','B','C'),(1,'123','123','123'),(2,'C','D','E'),(3,'456','456','456'),
    (2,x'00FF',x'01FE',x'02FD'),(3,x'00FF',x'00FF',x'00FF'),(4,x'00FF','ABC',x'FF00');
SELECT * FROM oldtable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable AS SELECT id,group_concat(CAST(col1||':'||col2||':'||col3 AS BLOB),'~') AS allcols FROM oldtable GROUP BY id;
SELECT * FROM newtable;
```

- **`:`** is used to separate the columns **`~`** being used to separate rows

The above results in 4 rows

- 1 for the 2 rows where id = 1,
- 1 for 3 rows where id = 2,
- 1 for the 2 rows where the id = 3
- 1 for the single row that has the id = 4

As per :-

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add separators, where you use the `||` notation?

Comment: @RadioControlled yes e.g. `col1||':'||col2||':'||col3` for a colon separator.

Comment: So it is not possible to cast mutiple rows into one blob using a row and a column separator? Or perhaps by building an intermediate table as above and then casting all allcols for the same id into another table's allrows?

Comment: @RadioControlled It is possible, example added to the answer.